# TensorFlow does not work after adding 2nd GPU (CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, multi-gpu

Today I have proudly installed a 2nd RTX 2070 to my Computer, to further speed up TensorFlow 2.2. But quite disappointing, the python scripts that worked on one GPU do not work anymore. I tried to boil it down to a minimal viable example, which works with the line

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/cpu:0"])
```

If i replace this line with any of the following lines

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
```

I get an error message like:

```
Starting training
Epoch 1/5
2020-05-23 22:52:59.205856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-23 22:52:59.400434: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-23 22:53:00.881437: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2020-05-23 22:53:00.898484: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example3.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "example3.py", line 70, in main
    model.fit(x=training_generator, workers=1, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch = len(training_generator))
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 644, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2420, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1665, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1746, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 598, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/frank/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at /usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py:916) ]]
  (1) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at /usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py:916) ]]
         [[div_no_nan_1/ReadVariableOp/_14]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_1034]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D:
 cond_1/Identity (defined at example3.py:70)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D:
 cond_1/Identity (defined at example3.py:70)

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function

2020-05-23 22:53:00.943669: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Here is the full code to reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, BatchSize, PicX, PicY, Color):
        self._BatchSize = BatchSize
        self._dim = (PicX, PicY)
        self._Color = Color

    def __len__(self):
        return 100

    def create_random_form(self):
        img = Image.new('RGB', self._dim, (50,50,50))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        label = np.random.randint(3)
        x0 = np.random.randint(int((self._dim[0]-5)/2))+1
        x1 = np.random.randint(int((self._dim[0]-5)/2))+int(self._dim[0]/2)
        y0 = np.random.randint(int((self._dim[1]-5)/2))
        y1 = np.random.randint(int((self._dim[1]-5)/2))+int(self._dim[1]/2)
        if label == 0:
            draw.rectangle((x0,y0,x1,y1), fill=self._Color)
        elif label == 1:
            draw.ellipse((x0,y0,x1,y1), fill=self._Color)                
        else:
            draw.polygon([(x0,y0),(x0,y1),(x1,y1)], fill=self._Color)     
        return img, label

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X = np.empty((self._BatchSize, *self._dim, 3))
        y = np.empty((self._BatchSize), dtype=int)
        for i in range(0,self._BatchSize):
            img, label = self.create_random_form()
            X[i,] = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img) / 255.0
            y[i] = label
        return X, y

def main():
    PicX = 300
    PicY = 300
    Color = (255,255,255)
    #save_some_pics(20)
    print("Starting a minimal, self-contained error reproduction")
    #strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])
    #strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0"])
    #strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device="/gpu:0")
    with strategy.scope():
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (9,9), activation='relu', input_shape=(PicX, PicY, 3)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((9,9)))        
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (9,9), activation='relu'))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((9,9)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))     
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    training_generator = DataGenerator(10, PicX, PicY, Color)
    print("Starting training")
    model.fit(x=training_generator, workers=1, epochs=5, steps_per_epoch = len(training_generator))
    test_generator = DataGenerator(10, PicX, PicY, Color)    
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_generator)
    print("Test loss {}, test accuracy {}".format(test_loss,test_acc))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running it on CPU works smoothly just as it did with only one GPU in the computer, also with

```
strategy = tf.distribute.OneDeviceStrategy(device="/gpu:0")
```

I get to normal training:

```
2020-05-23 23:11:56.890690: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-23 23:11:56.891333: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-23 23:11:56.891912: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-23 23:11:56.892554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7377 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-05-23 23:11:56.892873: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-23 23:11:56.893483: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 7377 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
Starting training
Epoch 1/5
2020-05-23 23:11:58.036789: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
100/100 [==============================] - 44s 438ms/step - loss: 8.8931 - accuracy: 0.4841
Epoch 2/5
100/100 [==============================] - 44s 437ms/step - loss: 0.8959 - accuracy: 0.6444
```

I am running out of ideas on what to try and also googling the error messages did not bring up much - any ideas highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After trying and reading a lot more I found the solution hidden [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29632)

Thank you srihari-humbarwadi and inkcherry!

The solution is to enable memory growth **on all GPUs** like that:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for p in physical_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(p, True)
```